# Incorrect pug/jade variable scope using jade4j

Tags: pug, jade4j

I am trying the following jade template. My expectation is that at the end of the loop the value of test should be 5

```
-test = 0
-var array = [1,2,3,4,5]

p before loop: #{test}
for element in array
  - test++
p after loop: #{test}
```

And actually is working in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/so5tqp35/ there the output is:

```
before loop: 0
after loop: 5
```

In my local webserver that is not working and I have

```
before loop: 0
after loop: 0
```

Without any errors appearing. I am using springboot with this plugin that takes care of the jade files.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>de.neuland-bfi</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jade4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

So it seems that there is something wrong in the workflow and the variable does not get overwritten. How can I find some hints on what is wrong?

Comment: Typo ? Your local webserver output is the same than the fiddle's one.

Comment: ops... definitely a typo. Fixed now and the fiddle / local is different.

Comment: Why are you using an undeclared variable? Wouldn't the problem be solved by just declaring it?

Comment: tried that one : - var test... but still the same results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the plugin that I am using : de.neuland-bfi

There is already a bug report addressing the issue: https://github.com/neuland/jade4j/issues/153